# Is there a dynamic way to post/get/patch... data by sending only models in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, http

is there a way or a library that can map the model of my choice to a http request so I can use it for fetching and posting data

For instance this is how currently it is

```
//SOME RANDOM MODEL
    TestModel{
    string name;
    string email;
    string someInfo;
    ...}
    
//SOME RANDOM HTTP REQ
    Future<TestModel> editTestModelAndFetchSomethingNew (TestModel tm){
    url = 'www.random.com' //ignore this its just for reference
    
    try{
     resp = await http.post(
    url,
    body: json.encode({
    'name':tm.name,
    'email':tm.email,
    'someInfo':tm.someInfo
    ...).then((resp){
    TestModel newModel = TestModel(
    name:json.decode(resp.body)['name']
    ...
```

is there a way more convinient way than writing it all down for instance to be like this:

```
 Future<TestModel> editTestModelAndFetchSomethingNew (TestModel tm) async {


    TestModel model = await (some library or some service).postModelRequest(
      url,
      tm,
      (some generator to map each of the parameters - example: tm.generate() ),
    ))!;

    return model;
  }
```

I have been searching for this type of solution for a while but havent found anything that can make this more convenient so Im curious if there is a way to make this or if there is a library for this. Thanks in advance

Comment: Try this package. It should be helpful for your use case: https://pub.dev/packages/retrofit

Comment: oh this looks interesting thank you, so does this only work with dio or http as well @AfridiKayal

Comment: Dio is a better rest client for flutter in my opinion. As far as I know, retrofit flutter works with dio in flutter. You can try looking for other resources online and see whether it is compatible with http if you still want to use it.